# AllowOverride security issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, indexing

There are all sorts of posts out there that advise you on how to add a .htaccess file to remove index.php from the URL. However, in order to get .htaccess files to work, the AllowOverride must be changed (usually to "All").

[This tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) explains that using .htaccess files for mod_rewrite is a misconception and can and should be done in the main config file.

I have been informed by my web security officer that - and I quote - "to change AllowOverride to All increases the risk to the web server as, if exploited, an intruder / hacker / opportunist could override the main servers configuration, which could allow them to get up to allsorts; this would be a serious security breach". I'm not sure how much weight this holds!

So my question is;

1. are there really serious dangers to changing the AllowOverride
2. and if so, why is .htaccess being recommended for removing index.php so widely on *Stack Overflow*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is little bit of security issue with `.htaccess` in the sense that if a hacker/intruder gets hold of your file system then they can modify rewrite rules and change the behavior of your website. However do remember that if a hacker gets hold of your DOCUMENT_ROOT folder then a lot more damage can be done by modifying/deleting any other code as well and you have much bigger problem in your hand.

However what `.htaccess` provides you is utmost flexibility by letting you control your website behavior, authentication needs **without need to make those changes in Apache config and restart it every time.** Especially in a shared hosting environments Apache config is not even accessible for website owners.